# ¿Como puedo importar datos de un archivo JSON grande a una base de datos MySQL con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo un archivo JSON de mas de 700MB que quiero procesar con PHP para insertar los datos a una base de datos en MySQL.

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
    $server = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '123456';
    $db = 'db';

    $conexion = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($db, $conexion);

    function Insertar($card_id){
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO card (card_id) VALUES ("'.$card_id.'")' ; 
        $resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: $sql. ".mysql_error());
        return true;        
    }

    $data = file_get_contents("all-cards.json");
    $cards = json_decode($data, true);
    $i=0;
    foreach($cards as $card) {
        Insertar($card['id']);
        $i++;
    }
    mysql_close($conexion);
    ?>
```

cuando lo ejecuto me salen el mensaje "PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"...

Comment: Si haces un var_dump a $cards qué te muestra?

Comment: simplemente no carga la pagina, creo que es por la cantidad de datos en el JSON porque cuando intento con un archivo mas pequeño (mucho mas pequeño) funciona normal

Comment: si el json no entra en memoria puede fallar

Comment: tengo 3GB de ram

Comment: ejecuto el php en la terminal del servidor y obtengo el mensaje "Violacion de segmento ('core' generado)... cuando lo hago con un archivo mas pequeño funciona normal.

Comment: seguramente sea memoria, fijate el ini o si por código podes aumentarle la memoria al php ( en ciertos casos y configuraciones tira un segfault en vez del clásico out of memory ) tendrías que ir probando valores empezando por el tamaño del json + 64mb, por ejemplo desde linea de comandos `php -d memory_limit=768M script_import.php`